# Get steam games from steam id

Tags: python, python-3.6, steam

I am trying to create a python program that get a steam id and return the games that the specific user have in his Library. I searched online and found nothing for python.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you have code?

Comment: What *did* you find?  If you have code in another language, then your problem is one of translation, not research.

Comment: write a sample for steam ink + id in your question.

Comment: I tryed translating the code but the moudle was available in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This ( I wrote a Class for You with fully error_handling, you can write this Code more efficient ... with BeautifulSoup or another package ( does not work for private user! ) ):

```
import requests, json


class SteamGameGrabber(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.url = ''
        self.headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
        self.start_tag = "var rgGames"
        self.end_tag = "var rgChangingGames"

        self.last_data = {}

    def send_request(self):

        try:
            response = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.headers)
            raw_data = str(response.content, encoding="utf-8")
        except:
            return [False, "Something Wrong! Connection Lost!"]

        else:
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return [True, raw_data]
            else:
                return [False, "Check Your Connection ( status_code is Not 200 )!"]

    def pars_data(self, get_input):

        def find_between(s, first, last):

            try:
                start = s.index(first) + len(first)
                end = s.index(last, start)
            except:
                return [False, "Parsing Error"]
            else:
                return [True, s[start:end]]

        if "<title>Steam Community :: Error</title>" in get_input:
            return [False, "I Can Not Find This ID on Steam Server"]

        if '<div class="profile_private_info">' in get_input:
            return [False, "This profile is private, I can not Decode it, sorry."]

        get_data = find_between(get_input, self.start_tag, self.end_tag)

        if get_data[0] is True:

            dict_data = json.loads(get_data[1].strip().lstrip("=").rstrip(";").strip())

            try:
                for box in dict_data:

                    game_id = str(box['appid']).strip()
                    game_name = box['name'].strip()

                    if game_name in self.last_data:
                        pass

                    else:

                        self.last_data[game_name] = game_id
            except:
                return [False, "Format is Wrong"]

            else:
                return [True, self.last_data]

        else:
            return [False, get_data[1]]

    def call_all(self, get_id):

        if get_id.strip() == "":
            return "Please Insert Your Steam ID"

        else:

            self.url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/{0}/games/?tab=all'.format(get_id)

            get_state_1 = self.send_request()

            if get_state_1[0] is True:

                get_state_2 = self.pars_data(get_state_1[1])
                return get_state_2[1]

            else:
                return get_state_1[1]



# Call This Class Now:

your_id = 'erfan1'

make_object = SteamGameGrabber()
get_result = make_object.call_all(your_id)

if isinstance(get_result, dict):

    print("Dict Format : ", get_result, "\n")
    print("Target ID : ", my_id, "\n")

    for names, appid in get_result.items():
        print(names, appid)

else:
    print(get_result)
```

Good Luck ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this developer website for steam, may you could use this with a python implementation.

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID

> **Steam ID as a Steam Community ID**
>
> A Steam ID can be converted to Steam Community ID for use on the Steam Community website.
>   Let X, Y and Z constants be defined by the SteamID: `STEAM_X:Y:Z`.
>   There are 2 methods of conversion:
>
> **For 32-bit systems**
>
> Using the formula  `W=Z*2+Y`, a SteamID can be converted to the following link: 
>      http or https://steamcommunity.com/path/[letter:1:W] 
>      The account type letter can be found in the table above. The path can be found in the same place after the slash symbol. 
>      Example: http://steamcommunity.com/gid/[g:1:4]
>
> **For 64-bit systems:**
>
> Let V be SteamID64 identifier of the account type (can be found in the table above in hexadecimal format). 
>      Using the formula `W=Z*2+V+Y`, a SteamID can be converted to the following link: 
>      http or https://steamcommunity.com/path/W 
>      As for the 32-bit method, the path can be found in the table above, again after the slash. 
>      Example: http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197960287930